# Return selected date in Pikaday plugin, within the plugin?

Tags: javascript, pikaday

I want to modify the JavaScript (no JQuery) [Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) date selector to show the chosen date in a header area, above the calendar.

To do this I have created a new function to render the header areas HTML:

```
renderHeading = function(instance, c, year, month, days)
{
        var opts = instance._o;
        var html = '<div class="pika-heading">';
        html += '<h3 class="pika-heading-year">' + year + '</h3>';
        html += '<h1 class="pika-heading-date">' + opts.i18n.weekdaysShort[day] + ', ' + opts.i18n.monthsShort[month] + '</h1>';
        return html += '</div>';
},
```

This works fine - it displays the month and the year.

However, I cannot figure out how to get it show the selected day number. My goal is to get it to show something like "Mon 1st Dec 2016" but I cannot get the 'Mon' and '1' to show.

The best I've been able to do is create:

```
window.setDateProperty = this._o.field.value;
```

in the getDate function and return that in my HTML render function, but this only works after 2 clicks and seems messy.

Would anyone know the correct way of returning the date string to within a part of the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found that using the following got it:

```
instance.getDate()
```

From there I could use the methods of [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to get the information I needed, eg:

```
var dayOfWeek = instance.getDate().getDay();
```

My full code:

```
 renderHeading = function(instance, c, year, month, days)
 {

    var dayOfMonth = instance.getDate().getDate(),
    dayOfWeek = instance.getDate().getDay(),
    opts = instance._o,
    html = '<div class="pika-heading">';
    html += '<h3 class="pika-heading-year">' + year + '</h3>';
    html += '<h1 class="pika-heading-date">' + opts.i18n.weekdaysShort[dayOfWeek] + ', ' + dayOfMonth +', ' + opts.i18n.monthsShort[month] + '</h1>';
    return html += '</div>';
 },
```